# SQLAlchemy: Is there a way to track the line number and calling class of a query done through SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Relatively new to SQL and SQLAlchemy, so please forgive any ignorance on my part as to the proper terminology or syntax.

I have a MySQL database to which many queries are made through SQLAlchemy from various files. I want to know from which file and from which line the queries are being made. Knowing which class is calling the query would be helpful as well. So I need some kind of identifying information from each query about its source file, or some way to retrieve that information.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm looking at Event listeners for SQLAlchemy and they do not seem to intercept any information about the code making the SQLAlchemy queries. It would also be too impractical to go into each file and insert comments into queries identifying the source file, since there are many such files.

In other words, is there a solution that does not modify the actual files from which the SQLAlchemy queries are originating?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do this. Are your files calling SQLAlchemy directly?

Comment: They are using SQLAlchemy to interact with the database, yes, unless I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a wrapper for the `session.query` method (assuming that's whats being used) and monkey patch (decorate) it. You can then employ [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) module to print the current call stack.

```
def query_wrapper(orig_query_method):
    def _query(*args, **kwargs):
        traceback.print_tb(limit=2)
        #print(traceback.extract_stack(limit=2))
        return orig_query_method(*args, **kwargs)
    return _query
```

And then wherever the `session` is initialized (hopefully, in only one file) manually apply the decorator.

```
from sqlalchemy import sessionmaker

# There should already be some initialization similar to this
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
session = Session()

session.query = query_wrapper(session.query)
```

So whenever `session.query` is called, it first its last calls that got the execution to that point.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll give it a try